# Метод, разбивающий строку на слова

Tags: java, методы

Прошу помочь с решением задачи. Нужно создать метод, который разбивает строку на слова используя разделитель(как параметр). Но есть одна главная деталь - НЕ использовать метод split, решение надо построить не используя его. Много раз пытался решить, но не получилось. Надеюсь Вы мне поможете. Буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Нашёл на просторах интернета.
http://proglang.su/java-examples/strings-split Смотри решение #3.

Comment: Да, но мне нужно разделить на слова и разделителем будет проблел(к примеру)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способов много. Наиболее простой для понимания, как по мне, выглядит так:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String text = "Прошу помочь с решением задачи. Нужно создать метод, который разбивает строку на слова используя разделитель";
        char delimiter = ' ';        
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();        
        int charStart=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (delimiter==text.charAt(i) || i+1== text.length()) {
                result.add(text.substring(charStart,i+1).trim());
                charStart=i;
            }
        }        
        System.out.println(result);        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Вы очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Вот, сделал.

Строка "if(string[g] == ' ')", это разделитель. То-есть в нашем случае пробел.

```
string = 'Its my string';
count = 0;
temp_string = '';

arr = [];

for(g = 0; g < string.length; g++)
{
    if(string[g] == ' ')
  {
    arr[count] = temp_string;
    temp_string = '';
    count++;
  } else {
    temp_string = temp_string + string[g];
  }
}

alert(arr[0]);
```

Comment: arr, это массив с нашими словами.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Сейчас попробую перенести

Comment: Очень странное решение. Как можно обращаясь к String использовать []. Оно у меня не работает(((

Comment: Не знаю почему так происходит, но последний элемент он не выводит. Если хочешь, можешь попробовать исправить. Но если что, просто ставишь в конец строки пробел и всё нормально. Можно сделать авто добавление этого пробела, смотри сам. Если помог, выбери как верный ответ.

Comment: Что бы последний элемент тоже выводился, нужно после цикла прописать arr[count] = temp_string, так как есть проверка на пробел, но не на конец строки.

Comment: Логично. Я особо не проверял, минуты две смотрел. Мне нужно репутация набирать, если мой ответ тебе помог, выберите пожалуйста верным.